# Is it worth learning Mathematica if I want to choose my career in Cloud Computing?

Tags: mathematica-online, cloud

currently doing my Masters in Computer Engineering. Is it worth learning Mathematica as I am thinking of pursuing my career in the field of Cloud Computing?. If yes, I really appreciate any good online resource to begin with.

Comment: I'm afraid this question may be off-topic here. The [guides](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (see also [ask]) explicitly say  asking subjective questions is off-topic. The focus here is on Programming on Wolfram Language, not career advice around Mathematica. Probably we could give you an answer in the [chat]?

Comment: In addition to what @rhermans says, https://community.wolfram.com/ might be a better forum to discuss open ended Qs.

Answer (score 1):

```
tools = {"LaTeX", "Mathematica", "Matlab", "MSOffice", "Python", 
   "Photoshop"};
careers = {"IT", "Cloud Computing", "Mathematics", "Engineering", 
   "Physics", "Teaching"};

StringForm["Is is worth learning `` if I pursue a career in ``", 
   First@#, Last@#] & /@ Transpose[{tools, careers}]
```

Now evaluate this:

```
StringForm["Is is worth learning `` if I pursue a career in ``", 
   First@#, Last@#] & /@ Tuples[{tools, careers}]
```

How many of your answers were "No"?